# Python Column Indexing out of order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse a CSV file using Python. What I've managed so far is that by using headers I've extracted the data from the file.

```
DIALECT = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
READER = csv.reader(csvfile, DIALECT)
LIST_READER = list(READER)
NEW_LIST = list()
headers = list()
column = {}

for row in LIST_READER[4:]:
    if str(row).__contains__('Patient Name'):
        headers = row
    else:
        NEW_LIST.append(row)

for h in headers:
    column[h] = []

for row in NEW_LIST:
    for h, v in zip(headers, row):
        column[h].append(v)
```

However, I'm facing an odd problem with indexing. Whenever I try

```
a = column['Home Address']
for item in a:
    print a.index(item)
```

The index values are all over the place. Heres a sample output

```
4098
0
0
4101
0
4103
0
4105
0
4107
0
4109
0
541
0
4113
0
4115
0
4117
0
4119
0
4121
0
4123
0
4125
0
```

There's a bunch of 0's in the middle, and the sequencing is in increments of 2 and at times there's random numbers in the middle.

Comment: Needs more info for the average joe to answer.  What's 'a' and can you pose a few lines of the file you're parsing.

Comment: I added what a is. The data is a CSV with an empty line between entries. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post the file here. Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah.. patients name.. I can imagine why.  Can you anonymize it?  (Just a half dozen lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are getting does make sense.

`a` contains a list of strings.  The first one is empty (the empty string), and then every other one is also empty.  The ones in-between contain various string values.

So your loop goes through pulling out each string.  Then the `index` operation goes through the list again and finds the **first** example of that string.  So for each blank string it returns zero (the first element), whereas for most non-empty ones it returns its own position.  But occasionally, where there are duplicates, it returns an earlier instance.

You probably want something like this:

```
a = column['Home Address']
for index,item in enumerate(a):
    print index,item
```

Also, as you read, skip the blank lines, which are what are giving you all those empty strings.

But your parsing approach seems odd.  Have you tried using DictReader which maybe does what you want?  Also you should see if you can do it while making fewer copies of the entire file.  Generally you can parse as you read.  Once you have the header line, for each line you read you can assign the fields into the right columns.

Something like this:

```
DIALECT = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
READER = csv.reader(csvfile, DIALECT)

for skip in range(4): # skip the first four rows
    READER.next()

# Find the header line
header = []
while 'Patient Name' not in header:
    header = READER.next()

# Now start parsing
for line in READER:
    if line == []:
        continue
    # `line` contains the data and `header` the headings so we can
    # do things like
    line_as_dict = dict(zip(header,line))
    # or build the column lists as before
```

I haven't tested this but it should get you started.